# SyntaxError while eval()'ing an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, eval

I'm trying to parse an object like that, using nodejs :

```
{
  1: [a, b, c],
  2: [d, e, f],
  ...
}
```

with `a,b,c,d,e,f` variables with defined values.

I really want that so that the object can really be readable (and writable by a human).

So, what I'm currently doing is opening a file containing the previous object, putting the data in a variable `data`, and then injecting

```
var a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,...;
```

just before the real content :

```
data = "var a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,...;" + data;
```

Finally, I'm using `eval()` to get a usable object :

```
my_obj = eval(data);
```

However, this does not work (at least using nodejs), with a SyntaxError on the `:` token after the second element of the object (so right after the `2` in the previous example).

To fix that, I'm now surrounding my object with :

```
data = "var obj = " + data + "; obj";
data = "var a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6,...;" + data;
```

And with that, it works.

The question is `why ?`

The optional question is : do you have a better way to accomplish what I want ?

Thanks!

---

**Real data before eval() call**

`data` with SyntaxError :

```
var a='a',b='b',c='c',d='d',e='e',f='f';
{
  a: 
  [a, a, a],

  b:
  [b, b, b]

}
```

Nodejs error :

```
undefined:6
  b:
   ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

Working `data` :

```
var a='a',b='b',c='c',d='d',e='e',f='f';
var obj = {
  a: 
  [a, a, a],

  b:
  [b, b, b]

}

; obj;
```

Comment: Could you give us the exact value of `data` before you `eval()` it please ?

Comment: @ldiqual Edited to add working and not working data before `eval()` call.

Comment: There is no assignment in your "not-working" `data`. You are just putting `{ }` without a `var obj = { }`. Additionally, what is the `obj` of the "working-data" last line supposed to do ?

Comment: @ldiqual `eval()` returns the result of the last statement executed. In my "working" case, that's `obj` (without it, `eval()` returns an undefined object). In the "not-working" case, I would expect the `{...}` object to be the last statement, and therefore to be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you first eval

```
{
 a: 
 [a, a, a],
 b:
 [b, b, b]
}
```

the brackets are in fact considered as block delimiters delimiting a block (as in if () { ... })

so you are trying to execute the code

```
 a: [a, a, a], b: [b, b, b];
```

which clearly is a Syntax error => you get the "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

In the second case, the evaluated code is valid javascript, which is why it works.

It is difficult to advise you on a better alternative. Maybe use JSON.parse instead of direct evaluation if your file cannot be trusted.

Comment: I did not know javascript have anonymous blocks, but it makes sense. Thanks !

Comment: I fixed my answer. "Standalone" blocks do exist in javascript, but do not create a variable scope. This can be confusing at times. check https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block for more explanations.